# How do I ask a user something then save the answer and repeatedly ask the samething over again

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested

Okay with the code below (I am a newbie please bear with me) I want to be able to ask the user the question:

```
System.out.println("Will the customer be adding any options to the order?");
System.out.println("1. Bed Frame ($39.99)");
System.out.println("2. Pillows ($59.99)");
System.out.println("3. Blankets ($129.99)");
System.out.println("4. No Options added. Enter No");
```

1. the customer will answer either 1-4 and then go through a loop and ask if the customer would like to add anything else/ are you sure you would not like to add anything.if no the customer is sent to another class (more questions). if yes customer is asked the same "will the customer ...." question over again.
2. customer adds lets say item 1 and goes through a loop and is asked if the customer would like to add anything else/ are you sure you would not like to add anything.if no is sent to another class. if yes customer is asked the same "will the customer ...." question over again. once the user is done answering the questions there answers will be saved and printed in the writeOutput() line along with thee names and prices of the products the customer added.

I know this is a loop but I dont know how to implement this kind of loop. Can anyone please help me out and fill in the blanks? Thank you. Below is the full code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class addons
```

{

```
    private int Option;
    private String Bed_Frame, Pillows, Blankets, No_Options_Added;
    private String Name;
    private double Price;
    public void readInput()
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Will the customer be adding any options to the order?");
         System.out.println("1. Bed Frame ($39.99)");
      System.out.println("2. Pillows ($59.99)");
         System.out.println("3. Blankets ($129.99)");
         System.out.println("4. No Options added. Enter No");
        Option = keyboard.nextInt();

       switch (Option)
            {
                case 1:
                   Name = "Bed Frame";
                    Price = 39.99;
                    break;
                case 2:
                   Name = "Pillows";
                   Price = 59.99;
                    break;
                 case 3:
                   Name = "Blankets";
                   Price = 129.99;
                    break;
                 case 4:
                 Name = "No Options Added";
                 System.out.println("No options added");
                   Price = 0;
                    break;
            }
    }

    public void writeOutput()
    {
        System.out.println(Name);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `while(true) { ... }` block, and you can add a condition after a question - and if the answer is "yes" - use `break` (not in a switch-case block!) to finish repeating the loop:

```
 public void readInput() {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {  //ADDED THE WHILE LOOP
           System.out.println("Will the customer be adding any options to the order?");
           System.out.println("1. Bed Frame ($39.99)");
           System.out.println("2. Pillows ($59.99)");
           System.out.println("3. Blankets ($129.99)");
           System.out.println("4. No Options added. Enter No");
           Option = keyboard.nextInt();
           switch (Option)
              {
               case 1:
                 Name = "Bed Frame";
                 Price = 39.99;
                 break;
               case 2:
                 Name = "Pillows";
                 Price = 59.99;
                 break;
               case 3:
                 Name = "Blankets";
                 Price = 129.99;
                 break;
               case 4:
                 Name = "No Options Added";
                 System.out.println("No options added");
                 Price = 0;
                 break;
            }

      //ADDED EXIT POINT WHEN TO EXIT:
      System.out.println("Is that All?");
      //read an answer
      if (*answer was yes*) break;

      } //ADDED A CLOSING BLOCK
}
```

The reading of the answer and determining what the condition should be is left as an excercise - since it seems like a tutorial assignment, and I don't want to spoil the fun! :)

Comment: You might want to add an exit condition :)

Comment: Yes, but that's probably not what he meant; sometimes the user doesn't know what he doesn't know.

Comment: yes exactly, if the customers is done adding items, there should be an option to quit (which will then go to the next class). also is it possible to add the name and price of all the added items at the writeOutput() line?

Comment: @user1757726: Read the edit and especially the last lines in the loop, I added a template for you to fill in there.

Comment: @user1757726: In order to print ALL the added items to the line, you are going to need to change the method to read from a data structure like an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), or concat a new items to `Name` using `Name = Name + " Pillows" (for example) - or something similar to it according to what exactly you need.

Comment: @amit we were instructed to not use arrays. Is there any other way of accomplishing my needs without an arraylist?

Comment: @user1757726: String concat, see the last part of my last comment. I believe however - it is a bit out of scope for the question originally asked.